# mxtransport setting for postfix does not work

Tags: postfix

I have server with postfix. Because google did not liked my IP address, I did used external SMTP server for delivering emails. I setup `check_recipient_mx_access` and I know it worked "sometime ago". Unfortunately today I saw it no longer works.

`main.cf` have following:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions       =
                check_recipient_mx_access       pcre:/etc/postfix/mxtransport

sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =       hash:/etc/postfix.host/sender_relay
transport_maps                  =       hash:/etc/postfix.host/transport
```

`/etc/postfix.host/sender_relay` and `/etc/postfix.host/transport` are empty.

`/etc/postfix/mxtransport` are as follows:

```
/google\.com$/              FILTER smtp:[my.smtpd.com]:2500
/googlemail\.com$/          FILTER smtp:[my.smtpd.com]:2500
/protection\.outlook\.com$/ FILTER smtp:[my.smtpd.com]:2500
```

I tried several ways, but they not seems to work.

Comment: "no longer works"? We are going to need the log lines emitted, because they probably pinpoint the problem. Send a mail matching that criteria and show what postfix logs.

Comment: NO errors in the log. on top of all, now it works... Only *major* change is I deleted the spool directory... I know exactly how it sounds. It could be something related to DNS. Will check today and update.

Comment: As I said, error log show no errors. Is like setting is not there. I did restart / reloaded several times, so is not related to "configuration not loaded".
I have another server with exactly the same problem, except is not urgent to fix. Will check very carefully there and will post answer very soon.

Comment: The best way to make sense of your statement "no longer works" is to show how exactly it is currently (not) working - just because postfix does not mark certain log lines as errors does *not* automatically make them unhelpful in diagnosing this. You also probably want to use `postconf -n` and `postconf -M` to dump your config in a way resilient against configuration file syntax problems leading you to believe a setting was used when it is not.

Comment: found the problem, please check the answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, mystery solved.

`check_recipient_mx_access` works only if the email comes from SMTP, e.g. telnet on port 25.

If I use `sendmail` or `mailx` the message go directly in the queue (postdrop) and these checks seems to be skipped.