# postfix transport and / or mxtransport is not trigerred if sending via sendmail

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix server with configured both `transport_map` and `mxtransport` that send via different SMTP server, if some criteria is present (yes, it checks for gmail/hotmail/live.com).

If I send via SMTP on 25 port, all works OK.

If I use `sendmail` executable (/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix), the transport is not checked and trigerred.

I understand the reason why it does not trigger - mail go directly in the queue, but question is - is there a way to fix this?

I got lots of comments that `transport_maps` should work, then may be the problem is with `mxtransport`.

Here is how my files looks like:

**main.cf**

```
...
transport_maps              =   hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtpd_sender_restrictions   =
        check_recipient_mx_access   pcre:/etc/postfix/mxtransport   ,
        check_sender_access     hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
...
```

**mxtransport**

```
/google\.com$/          FILTER smtp:[mail.smtp.com]:8025
/googlemail\.com$/      FILTER smtp:[mail.smtp.com]:8025
/protection\.outlook\.com$/ FILTER smtp:[mail.smtp.com]:8025
```

**mxtransport**

```
domain1.com     smtp:mx.mail1.com
domain2.com     smtp:mx.mail2.com
```

Comment: `transport_maps` works with `/usr/sbin/sendmail` too.

Comment: It does not. Will check and post again. I am with default version for CentOS 6 - is bit old. Could it be because of that?

Comment: `transport_maps` are checked when the queue is processed, not at the moment of a message being injected into the queue. I don't think this behaviour of `postfix` has changed in the last two decades.

Comment: I am clarifying the question.

Comment: I think you answered this question yourself already here https://serverfault.com/questions/1065595/mxtransport-setting-for-postfix-does-not-work/1065668#1065668 `smtpd_sender_restrictions` is checked only for incoming STMP connections.

Comment: yep. and seems is answered by me...
point is how to work around it?